# Use json-rpc through telnet?

Tags: telnet, json-rpc, bitcoin

It seems like you should be able to use telnet to manually make json-rpc calls.  However, when I try this, I get no response at all from the server and have to shut down the telnet client.  Do I need to send headers and/or somehow indicate that my input is complete?

Comment: sure, you could use telnet, but you'll have to recreate the entire communications protocol yourself. e.g. you can telnet to port 80 and simulate being a web browser, but you'll have to do the entire HTTP request header sequence yourself.

Comment: I've used telnet for HTTP before, but this is *not* HTTP... this is JSON-RPC

Comment: What server are you using? Have you set it up to run sockets?

Comment: The server is bitcoind

Comment: @JoelFan Do you have reason to believe (say from documentation provided with bitcoind) that it supports JSON-RPC over plain TCP (rather than the more common HTTP) ? If this is not true then your question is equivalent to "how do I plug this telephone into my banana"?

Comment: @JoelFan also, you've not given an example of one of your attempts to make JSON-RPC calls over telnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a small problem: you've completely misunderstood everything!

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29

It says right there that it supports JSON-RPC over HTTP. Nothing at all about JSON-RPC over plain TCP (what you're calling "Telnet" protocol).

You say "It seems like you should be able to use telnet to manually make json-rpc calls" but you don't mention how you came to this conclusion.

JSON-RPC is typically implemeted over HTTP, but *can* be implemented over plain TCP, websockets, or any bi-directional internet protocol. That being said, the overwhelming majority of JSON-RPC server implementations expose their APIs via JSON-RPC over HTTP.

As others have mentioned, you *can* talk HTTP from a `telnet` client and the payload of that conversation *can* be JSON-RPC.... if you know how. Just because you can doesn't meant you should.

Answer (score 2):

I have a project that will let you host a Json-Rpc server over telnet if you like. It doesn't come with telnet support built in, but it would be trivial to host it over telnet. See the console hosting example and just replace the console with a telnet server.

http://jsonrpc2.codeplex.com/